# Integrity Label management

Tags: mandatory-access-control

How can I read and modify the Integrity Labels of specified user folders and files on Windows 7 and later via the command line. For my use case, I need the command to be able to *read* the Integrity Labels without requiring admin privileges.

By Integrity Label, I mean:

1. an Integrity Level: typically `LOW`, `MEDIUM` or `HIGH`
2. a policy: `NO-WRITE-UP`, `NO-READ-UP`, `NO-EXECUTE-UP`, or arbitrary combinations thereof,
3. inheritance flags: e.g. `OI` (Object Inherit), `CI` (Container Inherit), `IO` (Inherit Only) and so on.

I cannot find a native Windows command to do this. I have tried a few 3rd-party apps, but have run into the problems specified below.

Here is what I've tried so far:

`CACLS.EXE` - no support.

`ICACLS.EXE` - fully supports (1) and (3), but not (2) - it only does `NO-WRITE-UP`.

`CHML.EXE` by Mark Minasi http://www.minasi.com/apps - fully supports (1) and (2) *and (3),*  <s>, but not (3) - you can only get (OI)(CI), or nothing</s>, but it doesn't support Unicode file or folder names.

`SETACL.EXE` by Helge Klein https://helgeklein.com/setacl - fully supports (1), (2) and (3), but incorrectly requires admin privileges just to *read* a mandatory label (which kills my use case).

Comment: This question was a straight request for a product recommendation (sorry, that's off-topic for this site). I edited it so that it focuses more on the problem. I think it is now a valid question, though maybe it belongs on a different SE site?

Comment: Please do not deface your question.